# Custom slider on active and on hover takes same properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I'm working on custom slider here I have written a loop it is working fine active slide and active dot pagination. On hover, I had wrote some CSS for active slide come top of all sliders. The problem is example`$( "#dt2").hover(){}` this hover function how can I merge with active slide this hover property I want to work on active as well as on hover in both cases I want to work this CSS using jquery.
Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this output.
**Hover on dot pagination you can see active slide comes top of the all other slides. So, this same property I'm trying to work on the active slide**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pdot").on({
    mouseover: function() {
      myvar = this.id;
      $('#sl' + myvar).addClass('fullVisible').siblings().removeClass('fullVisible');
    },
    mouseout: function() {
      $("img.image1").addClass('fullVisible').siblings().removeClass('fullVisible');
    }
  });

  $(function() {
    var $slideLoop = $('.slide');
    var $dotLoop = $('.pdot');
    var timeOut;
    var index = 0;

    function _loop(idx) {
      $slideLoop.removeClass('active').eq(idx).addClass('active');
      $dotLoop.removeClass('active').eq(idx).addClass('active');
      timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        index = (idx + 1) % $slideLoop.length;
        index = (idx + 1) % $dotLoop.length;
        _loop(index);
      }, 3000);
    };
    _loop(index);
    $(".pagination-dots, .inner").hover(function() {
      window.clearTimeout(timeOut);
    }, function() {
      _loop(index);
    });
    $(".slide, .pdot").hover(function() {
      $(".slide, .pdot").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    }, function() {
      $(".slide, .pdot").removeClass("active");
    });
  });

  // onhover on dot (this will work on hover as well as active slide)
  $("#dt2").hover(
    function() {
      $("#sldt1").css({
        "top": "-200px"
      });
    },
    function() {
      $("#sldt1").css({
        "top": "-100px"
      });
    }
  );
  $("#dt3").hover(
    function() {
      $("#sldt1").css({
        "top": "-200px"
      });
      $("#sldt2").css({
        "top": "-150px"
      });
    },
    function() {
      $("#sldt1").css({
        "top": "-100px"
      });
      $("#sldt2").css({
        "top": "-60px"
      });
    }
  );
  $("#dt4").hover(
    function() {
      $("#sldt1").css({
        "top": "-200px"
      });
      $("#sldt2").css({
        "top": "-155px"
      });
      $("#sldt3").css({
        "top": "-125px"
      });
    },
    function() {
      $("#sldt1").css({
        "top": "-100px"
      });
      $("#sldt2").css({
        "top": "-60px"
      });
      $("#sldt3").css({
        "top": "-30px"
      });
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  z-index: 0;
}

.image1,
.image2,
.image3,
.image4 {
  width: 490px;
  height: 490px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  width: 461px;
  height: 378px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
}

.image1 {
  top: -100px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.image2 {
  top: -60px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.image3 {
  top: -30px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.image4 {
  top: 0;
  left: 11px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fullVisible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.pagination-dots {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: -150px;
  top: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.pdot {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.pdot.active {
  width: 40px;
}

.slide.active {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pagination-dots">
    <div class="page-dot1 pdot" id="dt1"></div>
    <div class="page-dot2 pdot" id="dt2"></div>
    <div class="page-dot3 pdot" id="dt3"></div>
    <div class="page-dot4 pdot" id="dt4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <img class="slide image1 fullVisible" id="sldt1" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=244">
    <img class="slide image2" id="sldt2" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=1024">
    <img class="slide image3" id="sldt3" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=611">
    <img class="slide image4" id="sldt4" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [husna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9004424/husna): please make your question clear: I don't understand what you want exactly.

Comment: @Meziane I update the question check now.

Comment: Hi [Husna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9004424/husna) I will try to help you.
Use the newest *jquery* version: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: @Meziane yeah you can use latest version js

Comment: Your code is working: when you hover over any "dot" the correponding image is shown (hover over dot Nr. 1 shows image Nr.1, hover over dot Nr. 2 shows image Nr.2, and so on).
Now want you want to reach is: if image Nr.1 is active, dot Nr. 1 must be enlarged.
Am I undertanding you?

Comment: Hi [Husna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9004424/husna): YOU should use the last version.

Comment: @Meziane yes. On hover, I wrote some CSS top positions and all so the same hover property I want to use on the active slide like some `top` position.

Comment: @Meziane You can use any version I don't have any problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199402/discussion-between-meziane-and-husna).

Comment: Aren't you satisfied with my answer?

Comment: Here you are! [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/unhgc9p7/) is a working fiddle:.

Comment: @Meziane In your snippet see on hover nothing is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you confound the class *fullVisible* with *active*. So change the code-snippet to:

```js
var caroussel;
 
$(document).ready(function() {  

 
 $(".pdot").on({
  mouseover: function() {
   myvar = this.id;
   // console.log(`myvar= ${myvar}\n`);
   clearTimeout(caroussel);
   console.log(caroussel + " has been stopped");
   $('#sl' + myvar).addClass('fullVisible').siblings().removeClass('fullVisible');
   $('#'+ myvar).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
   // console.log(`#${myvar} is active.`);
   //console.log(`#sl${myvar} is fullVisible.`);
  },
  mouseout: function() { 
   $("#sldt1").addClass('fullVisible').siblings().removeClass('fullVisible');
   $('#dt1').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
   _loop(0);
  }
 });
 
  //startLoop();
  _loop(0);
});


function _loop(idx) {
 let slideLoop = $('.slide');
    let dotLoop = $('.pdot');    
 
 slideLoop.removeClass('fullVisible').eq(idx).addClass('fullVisible');
 dotLoop.removeClass('active').eq(idx).addClass('active');
 
 caroussel = setTimeout(function() {
        index = (idx + 1) % slideLoop.length;
        index = (idx + 1) % dotLoop.length;
        _loop(index);
 }, 3000);
 console.log(caroussel + " has been scheduled.");
};
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  position: relative;
}

#inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  z-index: 0;
}


.slide {
  width: 490px;
  height: 490px;
  opacity: 0;
  /*width: 461px; */
  /* height: 378px;*/
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
}

#sldt1 {
  top: -100px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 4;
}

#sldt2 {
  top: -100px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}

#sldt3 {
  top: -100px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#sldt4 {
  top: -100px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fullVisible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.01s ease;
}

#pagination-dots {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: -150px;
  top: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.pdot {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.pdot.active {
  width: 40px;
}

.img {
  /* background-color: red; */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="pagination-dots">
   <div class="pdot" id="dt1"></div>
    <div class="pdot" id="dt2"></div>
    <div class="pdot" id="dt3"></div>
    <div class="pdot" id="dt4"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="inner">
    <img class="slide fullVisible" id="sldt1" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=244">
    <img class="slide" id="sldt2" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=1024">
    <img class="slide" id="sldt3" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=611">
    <img class="slide" id="sldt4" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg">
  </div>
 </div>
```

if I were you, I will not use too much css-classes, the hover() function is superfluous and you don't need to set every time the top and left of your images, as they have different index-z.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/unhgc9p7/) is a working fiddle.

Comment: fullvisible you are binding with active but fullvisible is not working. And at the bottom hover functions, I want to implement on active also.

Comment: Let me add a jsfiddle for you

Comment: @[Husna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9004424/husna) have you seen the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/unhgc9p7/) I provided? It works smoothly, so what's the problem with my answer?

Comment: When hover on dot slides disappearing.

Comment: @[Husna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9004424/husna) That's right: When one hovers over the dots, the corresponding image is shown with a delay. This is another problem: I have answered your question. Accept my answer and I will help you to solve this second problem.

Comment: @[Husna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9004424/husna): I think that you need to stop the **_loop** on **mouseover** a **.pdot** element, and make this *.active*. On **mouseout** the **_loop** must start again from the *.active* **.pdot** element.
Please take a look at my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/unhgc9p7/) I simplified the code. But I am still working on it.

Comment: The [fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/unhgc9p7/) is now working as you want.
Please accept my answer or let me know your problem.